# Best way of searching data with passing multiple parameter in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

In the stored procedure to fetch data from this table based on search criteria entered on the screen like first name, last name, postcode, email etc...

while creating SP assumes the user can search by any one or more than one criteria at a time and SP should return all relevant results. This should be done without using the dynamic query string formation technique.

Can you please provide the best way of searching in the table with multiple parameters.

My code below, let me know this is the best way of searching,

```
declare @optionalParam1 NVARCHAR(50)='Anil', @optionalParam2 NVARCHAR(50)='sing'

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)       

SET @SQL = N'SELECT * FROM [EmployeeDetails] WHERE 1 = 1'

IF @OptionalParam1 IS NOT NULL        
    BEGIN        
        SET @SQL = @SQL + N' AND FirstName = @optionalParam1'    
    END        

IF @OptionalParam2 IS NOT NULL        
    BEGIN        
        SET @SQL = @SQL + N' AND LastName = @optionalParam2'    
    END        

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL,        
    N'@optionalParam1 NVARCHAR(50),
      @optionalParam2 NVARCHAR(50)'
    ,@optionalParam1 
    ,@optionalParam2
```

Comment: You may want to do some searching on 'sql kitchen sink query'. There are a number of good articles out there about how to optimized this sort of procedure.

Comment: This issue have been studied a lot by great names in the SQL Server world - [Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html), [Bertrand](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example) and [Gail](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/) are just three examples. Do your research.

Comment: Hi guys, I don't know why is given -ve vote someone my question....

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using dynamic query You can use  COALESCE

```
SELECT * 
FROM [EmployeeDetails] 
WHERE FirstName = COALESCE(@optionalParam1, FirstName) AND LastName = COALESCE(@optionalParam2, LastName)
```